# JIRA Query (JQL) to filter those issues within a certain set of EPICs

Tags: jira, jql

I am currently editing the Quick Filters of my Agile project in JIRA. And I need one where I see all the issues from a given set of epics. I am using something like

```
"Epic Link" in (ABC-1, ABC-18)
```

where ABC-1, ABC-18 are my epics. The problem with this is that I need to update the query everytime I add a new epic. Instead, I am thinking if there is a way of getting the list of epics that I care about via another search and merging the two into another query.

So for instance I have all the EPICs that I am interested (1, 18) with components set to "XYZ". 
So I want to do something like

```
"Epic Link" in ([Get list of EPICs with component XYZ])
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are several add-ons that help you to perform more complex queries.

For example if you use [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview), you can use the linkedIssuesOf function to do this. Your JQL could look like:

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("project = MyProject and component in ('A', 'B')", "is epic of")
```

Documentation is available [here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html).

There is also the [JQL Tricks](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.j-tricks.jql-plugin/server/overview) add-on which has the issueWhereEpicIn function which offers similar functionality. Documentation [here](http://www.j-tricks.com/jql-tricks-plugin.html).

There's also a similar question on Atlassian Answers [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/193025/how-to-find-stories-in-a-set-of-epics).

Answer (score 0):

there are more than one way - as I understand you correctly you like to search for:
`issuetype = epic and reporter = currentUser() and component = XYZ`